# (Swift) Prevent app doing anything while sliding

Tags: ios, swift, webview, slider, user-interaction

I have a `slider` below `webView`. What will be shown on the webView depends on slider's value.
 I am sliding and it works OK. I want to prevent my app, or more precisely my webView, doing anything while my finger is on slider(while I am moving a slider's circle). Then, after I finish sliding(remove my finger out of the slider's circle), app/webView should be able to do other things. Is this possible?

```
@IBAction func sliderButton(_ sender: Any) {  
    loadWebView()      
}
```

`sliderButton()` method triggers when user is sliding, but I want `loadWebView()` method to be called only after user stops sliding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For slider, you can do something like this,

```
sliderButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onSliderValChanged(slider:event:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc func onSliderValChanged(slider: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
        if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
            switch touchEvent.phase {
            case .began:
            // handle drag began
                print("handle drag began")
                break
            case .moved:
            // handle drag moved
                print("handle drag moved")
                break
            case .ended:
            // handle drag ended
                print("handle drag ended")

                //do for `WKWebView`'s user interaction

                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect. Just one more question, if user keeps holding slider on one value, can call a method `loadWebView()` after let's say 2 seconds, to prevent him holding slider too much time?

Comment: I think using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` you can achieve